# Определение типа данных на языке C

Tags: c

При вводе необходимо, чтобы переменная была обязательно числом, если вводится иной символ, программа должна запросить повторный ввод. Но чтобы определить что это именно какой то иной символ нужно определить его тип данных, а как это сделать я не знаю. Заранее спасибо за помощь)

Comment: неправильно подходишь к вопросу: нужно попробовать считать число, а если не вышло, то обработать ошибку... хинт: функции семейства `scanf` возвращают то сколько значений они успешно распознали, а также надо считать другими средствами то, что не смог считать при первой попытке... ЗЫ: стоит добавлять свой код прямо в вопрос, нажав серенькую кнопочку [edit]

Comment: То есть, стоит попробовать завести счетчик полученных значений?

Comment: Число - это никак не один символ. 55 - число. 48 - число. Потом, *какое* число - целое? вещественное? это разные вещи, потому что `0.314e1` - тоже число :) Непонятно из вопроса, как реагировать на ввод, скажем, `123abc` - как на число 123 или рассматривать его как ошибку...

Comment: Михаил, у вас путаница в терминологии. При вводе с клавиатуры вы можете получить только строку (ну или один символ как частый случай). Ваш вопрос в том, можно ли эту строку считать представлением числа или нет, а не в типе введенных данных.

Answer (score 2):

В двух словах, ответ выглядит так:

1. Вводим строку с помощью функции *fgets(...)*
2. *errno = 0;*
3. Пытаемся преобразовать введённую строку в число, с помощью функции *strtol(...)*
4. Проверяем значение переменной *errno*
5. Если есть ошибка - печатаем сообщение и переходим к пункту 1.

Из документации:

> Функция  *strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base)* 
>   преобразует  начальную  часть  строки *nptr* в длинное целое число
>   согласно системе счисления *base*, значение которой может быть от 2 до
>   36 включительно или равно специальному  значению 0.

Это кусок из моего рабочего кода:

```
unsigned int ConvertToUInt(const char *nptr) {                                                                
    unsigned long int ret_val = 0;                                                                        
    char *endptr;                                                                                         
    unsigned int rc;                                                                                      

    // Пытаемся выполнить преобразование                                                                                               
    errno = 0;                                                                                            
    ret_val = strtoul(nptr, &endptr, 0);                                                                  

    //-------------------------------------------                                                         
    // Проверяем все мыслимые ошибки                                                                          
    //-------------------------------------------                                                         
    if ((errno == ERANGE && (ret_val == ULONG_MAX || ret_val == 0))                                       
           || (errno != 0 && ret_val == 0)) {                                                    
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "Функция strtol сообщила об ошибке");                                         
        return 0;                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                     

    if (endptr == nptr) {                                                                                 
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "Строка не содержит цифр");                                                   
        return 0;                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                     

    rc = ret_val;                                                                                         

    return rc;                                                                                            
};
```

Замечание: в примере я использую *strtoul*, но смысл остаётся тот же.

Comment: У вас еще не отработан случай строки, скажем, `123abc`...

Comment: @Harry  Этот случай явно описан в доке: "Функция *strtol(const char * nptr, char ** endptr, int base)* преобразует **начальную часть строки**"

Comment: @Sergey: Но ведь автора вопроса не должно интересовать, что "написано в доке". У автора вопроса вполне конкретная постановка задачи, которую надо решить.

Comment: @AnT  *не должно интересовать, что "написано в доке"* - если программиста **не** интересует документация на программные средства, которые он использует, может быть ему стоит податься в депутаты государственной думы?

Answer (score 0):

попробовал так, превышается время

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    int length,k;
    while (k != 1)
    {
    scanf("%d", &length);
    if isdigit(length)
        ++k;
    }
    length = length * 4;
    printf("%d", length);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Какое начальное значение у `k`?

Answer (score 0):

**Тип данных**

Как уже написали в комментариях, у вас путаница понятий. С клавиатуры нельзя ввести тип данных "*число*", это в любом случае будет строка (она может содержать цифры, но это не важно в данном случае). Поэтому тип данных вам никак не поможет, это все равно будет `char *`.

**Представление числа**

Числа могут иметь несколько представлений в виде строки. Если проще - вариантов записи числа:

- 123 (десятичное целое)
- 0x123ab (шестнадцатеричное целое)
- 0123 (восьмеричное целое)
- b10110 (двоичное целое)
- 0.01 (десятичное вещественное)
- 10e2 (десятичное вещественное в [научной записи](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation))

Все, приведенное выше - числа. В вопросе вы не указали, какое именно текстовое представление числа вас интересует.

**Проверка введенных данных**

Теперь о проверке введенных данных. Способов несколько:

- Непосредственно при вводе с помощью `scanf`
- После получения строки ввода через функции преобразования строки в число (`strtol`, `strtoul`, `strtod` и пр.), данный способ уже приведен в ответе @Sergey

Я приведу пример использования `scanf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ClearStdin()
{
    int rv = 1;
    int ch;
    while (1) {
        ch = getchar();
        if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF) {
            break;
        }
        rv = 0;
    }
    return rv;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int num;
    int readCount;
    int isEmpty;
    while (1) {
        readCount = scanf("%d", &num);
        isEmpty = ClearStdin();
        if (readCount == 1 && isEmpty != 0) {
            break;
        }
        printf("Неверный формат числа\n");
    }

    printf("%d\n", num);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Обратите внимание на функцию `ClearStdin`. У нее два назначения: во-первых, если функция `scanf` не смогла считать необходимые данные, то они остаются в буфере ввода и программа будет пытаться считать их оттуда бесконечно. Во-вторых, данная функция проверяет, что буфер ввода был прочитан до конца и там не осталось лишних символов, таким образом ввод вида `123someword` не будет валидным.
В примере указан ввод с клавиатуры десятичного целого числа. Если вам нужен другой формат, посмотрите документацию на функцию `scanf`.